# Error in install.packages : package ‘RGtk2’ not installed because it is not built for UCRT

Tags: r, rattle

I tried to install rattle and RGtk2. I used

```
install.packages(
  "https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip",
  repos = NULL
)
```

to install RGtk2.

Then I received an error message saying

```
Error in install.packages : package ‘RGtk2’ not installed because it is not built for UCRT
```

I wonder how can I solve this problem?
Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

My solution is going back with R-4.1.0

Steps:

- Install R-4.1.0: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.1.0/
- Install Rstudio 2022.02.2-485: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download
- Install RGtk2: https://rattle.togaware.com/

Answer (score 0):

Graham has been testing and rewriting some of the instructions. https://rattle.togaware.com/ has a new instructions to install and run on a previous R version. There is also a Rattle 5.5.2 out a day ago, with some fixes.

Regards
Tony

Comment: I see the same error in R 4.2.1 with the current instructions, for windows. There's no silent, all user installer?

Answer (score 0):

Install RGtk2: https://rattle.togaware.com/

from above link, shows the following error

```r
install.packages("https://access.togaware.com/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)

#> installation of package ‘C:/Users/sales.co/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGmK8Uq/downloaded_packages/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).